# Gradle Duplicate Entry

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, twitter-digits

I integrated the Digits mobile sdk into my project and it wouldn't build anymore. It has some kind of a clash with gson library that i am using. I get this error during the build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/Gson$5.class
```

this is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }}
    dependencies {classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'}}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {release {...}}
    dexOptions {preDexLibraries = false
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"}
    packagingOptions {...}}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;}
    compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.5.5'
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;}}
```

Comment: is Digits mobile sdk imported using a jar library ?

Comment: no using this dependencies compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

Comment: did you try to Clean the project ?

Comment: post your `build.gradle` ;)

Comment: yes  i did but i have the same problem

Comment: what's inside dexOptions {...} ?

Comment: this   preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

Comment: Why did you add this ? Gradle is taking care of dependencies by itself and the problem you have should not happen.

Comment: i add the multidex Librarie to solve Android Dalvik 64k methods limit

Comment: 64k method can be solved using http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is the solution

```
compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.5.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude module: 'gson';
}
```

you need to add exclude module: 'gson'