# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' inished with non-zero exit value 2 in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have faced a unknown type of error.

here my build.grable:-

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.shoppingmazza"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile files('libs/fluent-hc-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-win-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar')
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar'
}
```

and here my logcat:-

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComDaimajiaSliderLibrary115Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubJakeWhartonViewPagerIndicator241Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I am new in android developing.Anyone can help me solved my problem. I near my to complete project. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try adding compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0' to your dependencies

Comment: no that is not works.

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your `android` block:

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project methods is over 65k. You should implement [Multidex](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Comment: after implement Mutidex `:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoStubImpl.class` i found this error.

Comment: Some of your libraries are using android support v4 library with different versions. We need to find them out :(

Comment: And our solution should be like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727582/gradle-duplicate-entry

Answer (score 0):

if your project has more than 65K method , you have to enable multiDex option in gradle ,, to make sure if the problem caused by multiDex ,, just run your app on a lolipop device if it running fine , then the problem is MultiDex ,

lolipop doesn't use Dalvik thats why it will running fine

Answer (score 0):

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

You are adding twice the **support-library v4**.

It happens because you are using

```
compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar'
```

You are getting this library from the jitpack.
[This library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) **adds the support library as a jar** and not as a gradle dependency.

It means that the pom file doesn't have a dependency and you can't exclude the jar file with gradle because the jar is inside the aar file (without a pom how can gradle know that these files should be excluded?).

You can check the files in the jitpack repo:

- [pom file](https://jitpack.io/com/github/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/2.4.1/ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1.pom)
- [aar file](https://jitpack.io/com/github/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/2.4.1/ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1.aar)

You can try to use the same library from other repo, for example:

```
`fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1`
```

You can check this [issue on github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/issues/343).